# What does this regex mean (0+1)*?

Tags: regex

I have this reggae (0+1)* and it is said that this is array of 0 and 1. * means "zero or more".

My question is what is exactly 0+1? Is it 01010101010 or random 0 and 1?

Comment: you said yourself, `* means "zero or more"`. By the same rules, `+` is "one or more".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex means that you can zero or more occurrences of group `0+1`.

And group `0+1` means: one or more occurrences of `0` followed by `1`.

Examples:

- 00000101001
- 01010101
- empty string

etc.